# What's the best way to create a model associated to a query instead of a table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to create a reporting app with Rails 4.
As a reporting system, it has a lot of SQL queries where the result is not like any table schema. I mean, a select query where I have some joins, unions and etc and the result will be something like a row with it's columns being result of subqueries, sums and etc.

Would it be possible to have a Model with no table associated, but I can use the "find_by_sql" on it, to instanciate an array of that model with the results of my query?
Something like:

Use "select table1.field1, sum(if(...,table2.field,...) as field2,  as field3 from...." as query, and return a array of a model "Result", where I can call a
array_of_result.first.field3?

Sorry if I'm not writing clearly enough.

**EDIT:** until now, sparky's anwser(http://railscasts.com/episodes/193-tableless-model) was the closest one, beacuse I want to use some of the ActiveRecord features, like specify a connection in the class(or even in a super class).

Comment: Sure, you can use the column names as the attributes or alias the column name to the attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can certainly create a Reporting model.

You would want to start off by creating a tableless model. Essentially, this can be as simple as a file in your models directory with

```
class Reporting
end
```

in it, and a controller with some appropriate actions and views. However, have a look at

http://railscasts.com/episodes/193-tableless-model

http://railscasts.com/episodes/219-active-model

which cover tableless models and what you can do with active model with respect to validations etc.

In your case, you say that you have some complex joins etc. Sometimes it's easier in the short term to SQLize these, but if you can use activerecord you should. Apart from anything else, this will allow you to define custom methods in your model which you can chain and make your Reporting controller much cleaner

Comment: The http://railscasts.com/episodes/193-tableless-model seems to be a way to go, even looking like a little "hacky".
Do you know if is it the best way to use a ActiveRecord-like with attributes from a query instead of single table?

Answer (score 1):

For pure reporting, especially when the result column names span multiple models, one alternative is to just pass the query directly back and deal with the result set:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute([raw SQL query])
```

You'll get back a result set, which is typically an enumerable set of row results, but check the documentation for your DB adapter to find out for sure what it's returning.

For example, if you're using PostgreSQL as your database with the `pg` gem, you'll get back an instance of `PG::Result` which you can then operate on in the following way:

```
 > results = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM customers")
=> <PG:Result >
 > results.count
=> 63   # the number of customers I have in this contrived example
 > results.first
=> { "count": "63" }
 > results[0]
=> { "count": "63" }
 > results[0]["count"]
=> "63"
```

You'll need to cast your return values to something other than strings. ActiveRecord will typically do this for you in your models since it knows the column types, but by doing a raw query you'll probably just get back strings that you'll have to cast yourself. If you're just doing a query to display it on a page somewhere maybe the strings will be sufficient.

I'm sure you'll be doing more sophisticated reports, but you'll notice in my simple example that the key `count` wound up being created as the accessor to the result of the `SELECT COUNT...` query. If you specify column names, or alias them, the keys in the resulting hash set will match the column names or the aliases you've set.